# Angular2 404 on page refresh localhost

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```html
// Angular module import
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'

import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component'
import { siteComponents } from './components'
import { loginForm } from './loginform/login.component'
import { LoaderComponent } from './loader/loader.component'

import { appRoutes } from './routes'

@NgModule({
     imports: [BrowserModule,
     RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
     ],
        declarations: [
            siteComponents,
            NavComponent,
            loginForm,
            LoaderComponent
            ],
        bootstrap: [siteComponents, LoaderComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule {}
```

I have the following code to implement routing for my angular2 application. The routes work well if redirected to but I get a 404 on refresh. I need help getting the routes to work on refresh. I am using http-server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Started the app allover again with ng cli and everything works fine.

Comment: this solution is not helping at all, you just decided to ignore the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn on the hash flag on forRoot as follows:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true,})
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you refresh the browser it tries to hit site.domain/actual-route, which obviously doesn't exist. One way would be as Jota suggested to switch to hash navigation. But html5 navigation is not too hard to achieve.

1. Use a more customizable back-end, such as express.js

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var path = require('path');
   var router = express.Router();

   router.use('/', express.static('app', { redirect: false }));
       router.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
       res.sendFile(path.resolve('app/index.html'));
   });

   module.exports = router;
   ```
2. Give https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server a try
3. Configure nginx or apache to redirect to index.html. Apache example:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule . index.html [L]
   ```

Comment: Okay Nick. Thank you. will try.